# changing the text when the page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I made a basic form that after you put in an input and submit the cookies show "welcome" + name

I added a second cookie that when you reload the same page the above text disappears and says "welcome back" + name.

I am new to using cookies and cant get the functionality working properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="user" type="user" name="user">
        <input id = "submit" type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <h1 id ="greeting" cookie_name ='name'></h1>
    <h1 id ="welcome" cookie_name='visited'></h1>

<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(Cookies.get('name')===undefined){
            $('form').submit(function(){
         var name = $('input').val()
         Cookies.set('name', name)
         Cookies.set('visited', 1)
        })

        }else{
            $('form').css('display', 'none')
            $('#greeting').append('Welcome ' + Cookies.get('name') + '!')
        }

    })


    if(Cookies.get('visited')===undefined){
            $('#greeting').text('Welcome again!')
        }else{
            $('#greeting').text('Welcome back ' + Cookies.get('name') + '!')
        }

<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually use `sessionStorage.setItem('name', name);` to store items and check if items are set like this 
`if (sessionStorage.getItem("name"))`

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

If Cookies is a must this code works for me just fine:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if (Cookies.get('name') === undefined) {
        Cookies.set('name', 'alexis')
        Cookies.set('visited', 1)
    } else {
        console.log('Name is already set');
    }

})

if (Cookies.get('visited') === undefined) {
    console.log('welcome for the first time')
} else {
    console.log('welcome ' + Cookies.get('name'))
}
```

Comment: This is for a class assignment so my instructor would prefer to stay with basic cookies with the jscookie.js library

Comment: Just updated my answer with cookies.I tested my code and it works with this library